# About Nginx status

Tags: nginx

This is my nginx status below:

```
Active connections: 6119
server accepts handled requests
 418584709 418584709 455575794 
Reading: 439 Writing: 104 Waiting: 5576
```

The value of Waiting is much higher than Reading and Writing, is it normal?

Because of the 'keep-alive' is open?

But if I send a large number of requests to the server, the value of Reading and Writing don't increase, so I think there must be a bottleneck of the nginx or any other.

Answer (score 2):

The `Waiting` time is `Active - (Reading + Writing)`, i.e. connection still opened waiting for either a new request, or the keepalive expiration.

You could change the keepalive default (which is 75 seconds)

```
keepalive_timeout 20s;
```

or tell the browser when it should close the connection by adding an optional second timeout in the header sent to the browser

```
keepalive_timeout 20s 20s;
```

but in [this nginx page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#keepalive_timeout) about keepalive you see that some browsers do not care about the header (anyway your site wound't gain much thanks to this optional parameter).

The keepalive is a way to reduce the overhead of creating the connection, as, most of the time, a user will navigate through the site etc... (Plus the multiple requests from a single page, to download *css*, *javascript*, *images* etc...)

It depends on your site, you could reduce the keepalive - but keep in mind that establishing connections is expensive. This is a trade-off you have to refine depending on the site statistics. You could also decrease little by little the timeout (75s -> 50, then a week later 30...) and see how the server behaves.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to fix it, as "waiting" means keep-alive
connections. They consume almost no resources (socket + about
2.5M of memory per 10000 connections in nginx).

Are the requests short lived? it's possible they're reading/writing then closing in a short amount of time.

If you're genuinely interested in fixing it you can test to see if nginx is bottleneck you could set keep-alive to 0 in your nginx config:

```
keepalive_timeout 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I really want to fix it, just don't know how to fix it. Yes, the requests is short lived. I will try to close the 'keep-alive'.